# How do I use multiple loops and store the output to multiple variables?

Tags: bash

I am trying to work with a text file named `itemlist.txt` that contains:

```
http://example.com/item-a
http://example.com/item-b
http://example.com/item-c
http://example.com/item-d
http://example.com/item-e
```

I've tried many different variations of code. Some will return just the item but not the url. I can't figure out how to assign `$url` correctly. This is about the closest I've come to achieving the desired output.

```
#!/bin/bash

while read url; do 
for item in $(sed "s/http:\/\/example.com\///g"); do
echo $item $url; done
done < itemlist.txt
```

The desired output is:

```
item-a http://example.com/item-a
item-b http://example.com/item-b
item-c http://example.com/item-c
item-d http://example.com/item-d
item-e http://example.com/item-e
```

But instead I am getting:

```
item-b http://example.com/item-a
item-c http://example.com/item-a
item-d http://example.com/item-a
item-e http://example.com/item-a
```

Can someone shed some light on how to do this correctly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't use `sed`; just use parameter expansion to remove everything up to and including the final `/` in the URL.

```
while IFS= read -r url; do
    item=${url##*/}
    echo "$item $url"
done < itemlist.txt
```

(Your problem, by the way, is that both `sed` and `read` are reading from `itemlist.txt`; `read` gets the first line, and `sed` consumes the rest. Your `while` loop exits after the first iteration.)

Comment: ++ for the explanation; overall, I'd still recommend a single tool invocation over a shell loop.

Comment: On second thought: the title suggests that _storing results in shell variables_ may be a requirement, though it's not clear whether that's a mere means to the end of _printing_ the result; either way: use _this_ answer if you need to store each line's results in _shell variables_; consider the `awk` solution if it's only stdout output that matters.

Comment: Agreed; shell has some rudimentary data processing abilities, but generally it should only be used in support of shell's main raison d'être, which is to execute other programs. Data processing in its own right should be done in a more suitable language, like `awk`.

Comment: I think I'm starting to get it but I'm confused about some things. So `##` says to remove all things `*` up to and including the _final_ `/` in the example above. But why doesn't it stop when it encounters `//`? And then suppose instead the url was `http://example.com/user-a/`. I would have thought the output from `echo "$item"` would be `user-a/` but that's not the case at all. I'm guessing that this means everything is being interpreted literally? But in that case how does one use parameter expansion for a url with a trailing `/`?

Comment: @user556068: It doesn't stop at `//`, because `##` means to strip the _longest_ prefix that matches pattern `*/`. For the same reason, a URL that ends in `/` will have _everything_ stripped, leaving the empty string. 
To handle this case you either need an intermediate step that removes  the trailing `/` - `urlNoTerminator=${url%/}` - or you can use `[[ $url =~ /([^/]+)/?$ ]] && item="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"`

Comment: @mklement0: Ok I think I have a better understanding now as far as how parameter expansion works. I can see that both of the examples you give work. And I even understand the first one which is pretty cool. The second one, though i know it works; why it works still eludes me. But I'll get it eventually. I appreciate everyone answering my questions. I know we're not supposed to say thanks in the comments but, thanks to you and chepner and jaypal for helping me understand this stuff.

Comment: @user556068: I appreciate the feedback; `=~` is Bash's regular expression-matching operator, which stores matches in array variable `${BASH_REMATCH[@]}` - see https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Conditional-Constructs

Answer (score 3):

<sup>This answer assumes that printing the results to *stdout* is sufficient; if, by contrast, you need to store result components in *shell variables* *for each input line*, see [chepner's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36829378/45375).</sup>

`awk` is probably the best tool to use here:

```
awk -F/ '{ print $NF, $0 }' itemlist.txt
```

- `-F/` splits each input line into fields by `/`
- `$NF` is the *last* field on each input line
- `$0` is the full input line.
- `print` prints its arguments separated by a single space each by default (based on built-in variable `OFS`; setting `OFS` changes that).

Answer (score 2):

Well, `awk` is probably be the best tool shown in [mklement0's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36829397/970195). However, no harm in having another option.

If your `sed` does not have `-r` option, just escape all parens. I have used `#` as the delimiter. You can use the conventional one by escaping `/` used as part of capture group.

The logic is pretty simple. You greedily capture everything until the last piece in a capture group. You capture the last piece in another capture group and just use them to suit your desired output.

```
$ sed -r 's#(.*/)(.*)$#\2 \1\2#' file
item-a http://example.com/item-a
item-b http://example.com/item-b
item-c http://example.com/item-c
item-d http://example.com/item-d
item-e http://example.com/item-e
```

Comment: ++; if you use `-E` instead of `-r`, it'll also work on OS X (`-E` isn't documented in _GNU_ `sed`'s `man` page, but it does work as an alias of `-r`).

Comment: Getting a bit rusty not answering on SO often. `;)`